# check if key exists in mapping of mapping

Tags: solidity

I have below data structure used in my solidity code.

```
// map(address => map(questionId => voted))
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => bool)) public mapUserVotes;
```

My requirement is that given an address, I need to check if it 'exists' in this mapping (ie has at least one quesitionId mapped to it).

I understand that all keys do exists in mapping, and maps to 0 by default.

Wanted to understand is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings initialize with default values, usually a form of 0 (e.g. uint is `0`, address will be `address(0)` etc.) but there isn't a default "null" for mappings as values. You may need a way to set the status of a user address being initialized. For example:

1. map address to a struct that includes the value mapping and an extra boolean **or**
2. creating a separate `mapping (address => bool)` that it set to true as soon as you add an entry to `mapUserVotes` for that address.

Comment: Yeah, actually I wanted to do it without using any extra variable/mapping. Seems there is no other way.
Anyways, I will mark this as correct answer. Thanks @razgraf